# Scala instantiation error with libGdx and Gradle

Tags: java, scala, gradle, intellij-idea, libgdx

I want to compile .scala files in my libGdx project only for Desktop but this error shows up

> Executing task 'DesktopLauncher.main()'...
>
> Executing tasks: [DesktopLauncher.main()]
>
> Task :core:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :core:processResources NO-SOURCE
>   Task :core:classes UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :core:jar UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :desktop:compileJava FAILED
>   warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6
>   C:\Users\cpepi001\Desktop\myGdxGame\desktop\src\com\mygdx\game\desktop\DesktopLauncher.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
>           new HelloScala();
>               ^
>     symbol:   class HelloScala
>     location: class DesktopLauncher
>   1 error
>   1 warning
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':desktop:compileJava'.
>     Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
>   Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
>   See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> BUILD FAILED in 0s
>   3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
>   2:10:42 PM: Task execution finished 'DesktopLauncher.main()'.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new LibGDX project
2. Right click to desktop module -> Add framework support -> Scala (v2.10.4)
3. Make a new .scala file inside the desktop module
4. Inside DesktopLauncher.java instantiate the class (i.e. `new HelloScala);`)

Also I try [this guide](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Using-libgdx-with-Scala) with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution

1. build.gradle(Project `<project_name>`)

   - Add the Scala plugin to the `project(":core")` section: `apply plugin: "scala"`
   - In the dependencies include the scala library: `implementation "org.scala-lang:scala-library:$scalaLibraryVersion"`
2. build.gradle(Module: desktop)

   - Change sourceSets.main.`java`.srcDirs = [ "src/" ] to sourceSets.main.`scala`.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]